# How to calculate the amount of bulk capacitance for motor drive?

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, dc-motor, motordriver

I'm working on designing a 3-phase motor drive with an input voltage of 22 V and a maximum phase current of 160 A that might go a bit higher. The switching frequency is around 100 kHz and the maximum allowable ripple voltage is around 4 V.

Would anyone show me the procedure to calculate the amount of DC link bulk capacitance (capacitor) that is needed for this operation?

Comment: Why would you need any (based purely on the info in your question)?

Comment: Because when the motor conducts and then stops due to some mechanical reason and due to back emf, some current conducts in reverse direction and goes through mosfets. Those current should go somewhere instead of mosfet and charge the capacitors

Comment: Why can't the power supply absorb that energy?

Comment: It's a battery. The main idea is to protect the switches in the motor drive. Not to burn them and absorb the reverse current and increased voltage.

Comment: A battery would hold the voltage constant and, realistically, that's all that a bulk capacitor is trying to do. Either way, the MOSFETs should not burn because the current passed back to the supply is the same in either case (battery or bulk capacitor). Do, you begin to see that without specifying the technical details of the supply it's pointless trying to answer.